# Sharepoint Online Popular Items Webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, popularity-trends

I'm looking to display the most popular items from a document library, but i cannot find an out of the box solution. I have seen that SharePoint 2013 has a solution for this, but i guess it didnt get carried over.

I am using a Team Site with Modern pages, so that rules out the Content Search web part and i cant seem to configure Highlighted content to sort by popularity.

Is there an out of the box solution to display the most popular items within a document library? (optimally with filtering functionality based on managed properties)

I would like to avoid creating a custom SPFx web part if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you configure "Highlighted Content" with "this site" or "this site collection", you can set it sort by "Most viewed":
[image]

However, if you choose a library, there is no "Most viewed" in **Sort by** option.

Currently, there is no OOB modern web part to achieve your requirement, you need to develop a custom spfx web part to do that.

Comment: This will do the job, thanks! I am using a custom managed property on the items in the library, so applying a filter on that seems to pull the correct information.